# Which of the following data structures is scalable in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to build an event analytics system, where I can record and query events that a user has done, for example on a website.

My naive idea of the data model was simply a collection of event documents, each event including the userid, event type, and so on. So I thought something like this:

```
{ userid: Joe, event: homepage }
{ userid: Mike, event: homepage }
{ userid: Joe, event: productsPage }
{ userId: Joe, event: accountSettings }
{ userId: Joe, event: checkout }
etc
```

But now I'm struggling to figure out how to do some of the queries I'm most likely to be able to want to do.

For example, I want to say "Give me a list of all users who have visited the homepage AND the products page AND the checkout page"

Seems to me I would need to use my application code to do this, rather than elasticsearch? And I would need to do something like:

```
Step 1: select all users who have done 'homepage'
Step 2: select all users who have done 'products page'
Step 3: select all users who have done 'checkout page'
Step 4: build a list of only those users who appear in all 3 lists.
```

If I have a userbase of 20 million users, I risk bringing huge lists of data into my application?

An alternative would be to have one document per user, so that Joe looks like

{ userid: Joe, event: [ homepage, productsPage, accountSettings, checkout ] }

and so on.

But then that would involve updating this document every time the user did something. Since elasticsearch writes a new record rather than updating in place, that would involve a horrendous amount of rewriting, given that each user might do say 5000 events in a year, and spread across different days. Not to mention rewriting of the index?

Is there an idiomatic way I'm missing of accomplishing a database by user that can handle regular updates to each user, and buid indexes that allow for fast querying of that data by multiple criteria - eg users who have done eventA AND eventB AND eventC?

Many thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kibana for Visualizing Data stored in Elasticsearch.

> You can use this type of events itself:-

```
{ userid: Joe, event: homepage }
{ userid: Mike, event: homepage }
{ userid: Joe, event: productsPage }
{ userId: Joe, event: accountSettings }
{ userId: Joe, event: checkout }
etc
```

After storing your data in Elasticsearch, You can use Kibana and create visualizations specifying AND Filters over the event field.